# jq select input based on values in array

Tags: jq

I have a list of country codes like FR, IT, DE and have been trying to figure out how to use this in a select statement.  I was doing something like

```
cat stuff | jq -c '.[]| select(.country_iso3166_alpha2 == "US")'
```

But then my list grew to a large number of countries I want to match on.  So I tried using IN since I'm using jq 1.6 and did something like this:

```
eu=("FR", "IT"); cat stuff | jq -c '.[]| select(.country_iso3166_alpha2 IN($eu)'
```

I've been reading the docs and looking at the cookbook but it's not making any sense to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--argjson` to pass the list to `jq` and `IN` to select the matching entries.

```
jq -c --argjson eu '["FR", "IT"]' '.[]| select(.country_iso3166_alpha2 | IN($eu[]))' <stuff
```

Broken out to show the individual parts:

```
jq -c \ 
    --argjson eu '["FR", "IT"]' \ 
    '.[]| select(.country_iso3166_alpha2 | IN($eu[]))' \ 
    <stuff
```

1. invoke jq with compact output
2. pass in the list of countries as a json array named "eu"
3. select using the `IN` operator, unpacking `$eu[]` to get its values
4. redirect the input file into `jq`

Comment: That's a great answer.  Thanks for sharing an example using IN.

Comment: @alanlaird if one of our answers has solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the checkmark for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jq does not understand bash arrays.

Things would probably be simplest if you can arrange to have your shell variable be a string representing a JSON array:

```
eu='["FR", "IT"]'
jq -n --argjson eu "$eu" '$eu'
```

Or if you prefer:

```
eu='["FR", "IT"]' jq -n 'env.eu | fromjson'
```

Another possibility would be to write your bash array into a file, and then slurp the file.

There are also many variants of the above....

Comment: That's a great answer.  Thanks for providing the variable declaration example!